# retrieve users input with PHP and echo it

Tags: php, input

I was wondering if it was possible to take HTML user input using PHP (preferably the ID or something I can use numbers in) and to save confusion just echo it back.

So I have some example code here:

```
<input type="number" maxlength="3" name="test" id="1">
<input type="number" maxlength="3" name="test" id="2">
<input type="number" maxlength="3" name="test" id="2">
```

What I was looking for is a way where I could use their input and well.... echo it back for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you already know how to submit a form you can use php on the other side like this to echo it out

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
$userinput = $_POST['name'];
echo $userinput;}
?>
```

in your example all three inputs are named "test" so youll need a different name for each one. My example above uses the "name" of the input to capture it. If your using "GET" change my $_POST['name'] to $_GET['name']

Answer (score 1):

Which  method did you use for these inputs? Name them differently, then retrieve the data with:

```
 <?php echo $_GET['test1']; ?>
 <?php echo $_GET['test2']; ?> 
 <?php echo $_GET['test3']; ?>
```

If you used POST type in the input method, then switch for:

```
<?php echo $_POST['test1']; ?> 
<?php echo $_POST['test2']; ?>
<?php echo $_post['test3']; ?>
```

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm open to using any type of method to submit it to PHP. But I wanted to be able to have the PHP on the same page so I can echo on the same page.